# Find out missing month in the list of Dates arranged sequentially in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a colomn of DateTime type containing a each months 1st date. I want to find out the months which are not in the colomn any suggestion..??

Example:

```
Dates_Of_Each_Months
----------------------
01/01/2017
02/01/2017
04/01/2017
06/01/2017
05/01/2016
07/01/2016
09/01/2016
10/01/2016
```

Expected Output

```
Missing_Months
--------------
03/01/2017
05/01/2017
06/01/2016
08/01/2016
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: From which date

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Creating a table to insert your data. 
-- You can use your database table here.

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
 DateVal DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT CAST('01/01/2017' AS DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT CAST('02/01/2017' AS DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT CAST('04/01/2017' AS DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT CAST('06/01/2017' AS DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT CAST('05/01/2016' AS DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT CAST('07/01/2016' AS DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT CAST('09/01/2016' AS DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT CAST('10/01/2016' AS DATETIME)


-- Creating another table variable that will contain the range


DECLARE @tblRange TABLE(
 DateValue DATETIME
)
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = ''
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = ''

-- Get the min date and max date from your range.
;WITH DATES(MINDATE,MAXDATE) AS (
    SELECT (SELECT MIN(DateVal) FROM @tbl) A, 
    (SELECT MAX(DateVal) FROM @tbl) B
)
SELECT @startDate = MINDATE, @endDate = MAXDATE FROM DATES;


--Populating the range
--Get the difference between min and max in months
DECLARE @seqDays INT;
SELECT @seqDays = DATEDIFF(m, @startDate,@endDate)

DECLARE @val INT = 1
WHILE(@val <= @seqDays)
BEGIN
 --Generate the range with the month
 INSERT INTO @tblRange VALUES(DATEADD(MONTH, @val, @startDate))
 SET @val = @val + 1
END

--Get the months not present in original data
SELECT DateValue FROM @tblRange WHERE DateValue NOT IN (SELECT DateVal FROM @tbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (A_DATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT '2017-02-18 17:46:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-05-18 17:46:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-04-18 17:46:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-09-18 17:46:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-09-18 17:46:00'

CREATE TABLE #TAB1 (G_DATE varchar(255))

INSERT INTO #TAB1
SELECT 'January'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'February'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'March'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'April'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'May'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'June'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'July'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'August'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'September'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'October'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'November'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'December'

SELECT * FROM #TAB1
EXCEPT
SELECT DATENAME(month, A_DATE) FROM #TAB

DROP TABLE #TAB1,#TAB
```

Try the above Query it may help